# Cuando mi validación de un form falla, ¿Cómo posicionarme en mi form fallido sin usar la propiedad required?

Tags: php, html, laravel, formularios

Estoy haciendo un formulario con su validación, lo que se me pidió es que no use la propiedad required en sus campos sino que con laravel puro lo validara y si fallara mostrara un mensaje bajo los input que no pasaran la validación. Eso ya esta logrado, el problema es que si falla la validación como la pagina es larga quiero que me posicione de nuevo en el formulario que fallo. Espero y me puedan ayudar.

Esta parte es como yo muestro los errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es mi codigo de validacion:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required'
        ],[
            'name.required'=>'El campo nombre es requerido',
            'email.required'=>'El campo email es requerido',
            'message.required'=>'El campo mensaje es requerido'
        ]); 

        ContactUs::create($request->all());

        Mail::to('correo@prueba.com')
            ->cc('correo2@prueba.com')
            ->send(new MessageReceived($request));
            
        alert()->success('Tu mensaje fue enviado exitosamente.', 'Enviado!');

        return view('home');
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres controlar la redirección después de un error de validación en el request te aconsejo que utilices el facade [Validator](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manually-creating-validators) que es más flexible.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
     'name' => 'required',
     'email' => 'required|email',
     'message' => 'required'
], [
     'name.required'=>'El campo nombre es requerido',
     'email.required'=>'El campo email es requerido',
     'message.required'=>'El campo mensaje es requerido'
 ]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect('la/ruta/retornar')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
}
```